# nodejs server doesn't handle requests when deployed remotely

Tags: node.js, deployment, socket.io

I have a node.js app (with websockets) that works locally. I ssh into my remote server, and run `node server.js` (the same thing I do locally). I get my logging text "connected and listening on (port) 3000".

When running locally, I go to `https://localhost:3000`. for the remote server, I can't seem to find where the node server is handling requests. I've tried `https://mydomainroot.com:3000` and `https://mydomainroot/folder/containing/serverjs`, and some minor variations on that theme.

None of these requests seem to be getting handled by my node server (it should log something like "received GET request to /main"). Sockets are also unresponsive.

I'm using A Small Orange hosting, if that matters.

I could just navigate directly to `main.html`, but it doesn't solve the websocket problem.

My likeliest hunch is something to do with routing, but I've run out of ideas of where to look next. Help?

code:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log("Received request for /");
  res.sendFile('main.html', {root: __dirname + '/public'});
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("received socket connection");
  users.push(socket);

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    if (socket.player)
      var data = "updates"

      io.emit(data);
  });

  socket.on('move', function(move) {
      //send move to everyone except sender
      io.emit("updates");
    }

  });
}); // socket connection ends

function start() {
  http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("connected and listening on 3000");
    start();

  })
};

function start() {

  // this emits the game state to every connected socket
  io.emit('Initial state');

  // this triggers end of turn
  setTimeout(nextTick, 5000);

}

function nextTick() {
  io.emit('updates');
  start();
}

start();
```

Comment: Per [this example code on Small Orange hosting site](https://help.asmallorange.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/286/1/getting-started-with-nodejs-on-a-small-orange), it appears that you are allowed to both run nodejs and to listen on port 3000.  I would guess that your domain is not hooked up properly to the IP address where your server is running.  You can start by checking the IP address of your nodejs server and the IP address of your domain and see if they are the same.

Comment: Have you tried running `curl localhost:3000` on the remote server and see if it returns anything?

Comment: Where'd you go?  We're trying to help you and you seem to have just disappeared.

Comment: Excuse me, it seems you have unnecessary closing brackets on function **mode** i.e. right after **io.emit("updates");**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're hardcoding to port 3000, you should check if your host provider actually allows that port to be accessed. You may have to configure your firewall to make that port publicly available.